# SVN - Merge branch changes in the Trunk

Tags: svn, branch, branching-and-merging, svn-trunk

we are working on 2 concurrent releases, one is the branch and other is trunk. and every change that goes to branch must be merged in trunk. this takes lot of time if we are working on a big functionality. thus I want to automate this process i.e. every time there is a change in the branch .. these changes are merged with trunk.

For the same, I am exploring SVN and thinking to write a script that does this. would anyone know how can I achieve this, is there any tutorial of some sort ?  I have already referred to various articles like [this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html).

So far I have not been able to get it working.

Comment: It's impossible, because every merge could lead to conflicts which have to be resolved by a human understanding what must be done.

Comment: yes true, but wouldn't merge command handle that ?

Comment: The merge command does everything it can, but for example, if you delete file A in trunk, and add 25 lines of code to file A in branch, how could SVN know what it has to do with these 25 new lines of code? The design has changed in trunk, and the change in branch must be manually rewritten to accomodate with the new design.

Answer (score 1):

I try to repeat the question with my own words: You are planning to make a release *v0.1* in the near future, but there is still a lot of work to do. Shortly after the release, there will be release *v0.2* with some additional features - being worked on already. How to do this with Subversion?

I recommend doing it the other way: Create the release branch for *v0.1* as late as possible. Create one ore more feature branches for the features, that are not part of the first release. The trunk changes can be easily merged into the feature branches with `svn merge ^/trunk` (works very well due to merge-tracking). Create the release branch when most work is done, and reintegrate the feature branches afterwards into the trunk.

After the release branch has been created, changes should be made on the trunk, and merged from the trunk to the release branch - so-called cherry-picking. It requires a bit more effort, and I recommend it, because in my opinion, development should happen on the trunk and its feature branches - and not on release branches.